# Python27 building exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, executable, pyinstaller

I wrote a one line script with a print statement to learn how to build executables with pyinstaller. I am using 32 bit Python 2.7.15 on Windows 10, and I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have read about this specific error, but none of the solutions seem to add up in my case because I am not importing any libraries. Is it possible that the version of pyinstaller I have installed is 64 bit? I can't figure out where to determine that.

Any input is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it on a different computer and it worked fine. Same Python installation. Must be some issue with my computer.